# Confused about how nested for loops could be both O(n!) and O(n^2)

Tags: python, for-loop, big-o

Let's say there is a simple nested for loop:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        print(i*j)
```

This is very easily seen to be `O(n^2)` by pretty much everyone. Now if we modify the nested for loop:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        print(i*j)
```

It's going to something along the lines of `n x n-1 x n-2 ... x 1` right? This would be the same `n!`, which should be a horrendous upper bound. So what am I missing here? Why is the smaller version of the for loop, which is clearly  skipping a couple of iterations of the loop resulting in a big o notation that is worse?

Comment: I'm sure there is a very obvious answer to this that I am missing.

Comment: Concerning the "very easily seen", I disagree: You leave out the complexity of `print()` and `i * j`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        print(i*j)
```

- On the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop does n operations.
- On the second one, n-1 operations.
- On the third one, n-2 operations.
- ...and so forth, until the inner loop does only 1 iteration.

n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 = O(n^2), where would the multiplication come from?

Note that in a pedantic sense, O(n^2) is also O(n!). That is, O(n!) includes functions that are O(n^2) (and then some).

Comment: That's not right, O(n!) ≫ O(n²).

The big O notation is more strict, O(n!) doesn't include O(n²).

Comment: @sabic f(n) = O(g(n)) means f grows "not faster" than g. If f(n) grows "not faster" than n^2, it also grows "not faster" than n!

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of Θ, which is the "neither faster nor slower" one.

Answer (score 4):

That calculation should be `n + n-1 + n-2 ... + 1`, which is O(n²).

Comment: Yes. This is it. I was confused between the addition and the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new. Due to my understanding, I think

for i in range(0,n) -> n times
for j in range(i,n) -> n-i times

Because there are just 2 loops which mean n * (n-i) for whole operations. It should be only O(n^2).